# Which methods absolutely need Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, microsoft-fakes

My team is working on the development of an application running for several years already, but no unit test has ever been coded. Now that we wish starting doing so, we realise we cannot possibly go over all the existing methods to test them because that would take years of work.

The question is : **how can one decide which method absolutely need unit testing, and which doesn't?**

Would you rather unit test a method that is often called or a method that is often modified? 
I read that Unit Testing is rather inefficient on DAO classes. Should I restrain the tests to methods containing logic?

Most important : **Will the tests put in place any useful as far as only part of the application is unit tested?**

Comment: I answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672866/refactoring-wpf-mvvm-for-increased-testability/26675374#26675374) - perhaps it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**how can one decide which method absolutely need unit testing, and which doesn't?**

This is a difficult question to answer without knowing about your code base and what its history and future are.  But in general, write tests for the parts of the code that are hard to understand, will get modified in the near future or are known to have bugs.  When testing legacy applications, the best bang for your buck is to have tests make the program both easier to maintain going forward, to fix bugs and to keep old bugs from coming back.

**Would you rather unit test a method that is often called or a method that is often modified?**

As stated above, it depends.  Is the method that is called often trivial? Easy to understand?  I would probably lean towards "often modified" just to make future development easier.  But ideally both should get tested.

**I read that Unit Testing is rather inefficient on DAO classes.**

I don't know where you read that.  Unit testing can be very efficient with DAOs if you use mock objects.

**Will the tests put in place any useful as far as only part of the application is unit tested?**

Any tests are useful.  A program that is only 10% covered by tests is better than a program with 0% coverage.  Especially if that 10% is the most important or trickiest part of the program.

If you haven't read it yet, I highly recommend Michael Feather's *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* where "legacy code" means code that doesn't have tests.

Comment: I think you may have misread "Should I restrain the tests to methods containing logic?". You seem to be in violent agreement without realising so ;-)

Comment: Concerning DAO classes, aren't mock objects avoiding call to database, meaning in the end you don't really test it? And as Duncan said, I think there is a misunderstanding on the last point :)

Comment: @realUser404: correct, you read right. Dkatzel here might have misunderstood.. Same as with last point. Perhaps you could improve your answer to answer *actual* points?

Comment: @realUser404 depending on what you are mocking.  Mocking the database will make sure all your code that tries to interact with your database is working correctly.  Using mocks, you can create scenarios that are not normally possible with a real database.  You can also mock out the real database with an in memory version or a different "real" test database to actually try your query logic.

Comment: @Duncan oops, you're right.  I've updated my answer and I also see the OP updated the question with new questions so I have updated my answer for that as well

Answer (score 0):

Some people create unit tests for getters and setters and insist on 100% code coverage.

Practical people will test those methods that need testing. What this means will depend on your intelligence and discernment of what constitutes a method that needs testing.

[Some people](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) however consider the minimum size of a unit is the class and that tests should be created to test a class (and sometimes its associated classes).

In short, forget any kind of dogmatic principle about unit testing, what matters is the quality of your code. Like agile development, its what helps you to achieve that goal that is important. So if you feel your DAO objects will not benefit from testing, then don't bother - spend that time you would have spent doing something more productive instead.